# Loop messing up pattern in Java?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I seem to be having a bit of trouble with my loop. The first part of the loop works fine, but the second part isn't printing out the correct number of spaces. It should start at (N - 1) * 2 spaces and go down to zero, decreasing by two each time, or at least that's what I'm trying to accomplish.

It has to be a for loop and I thought that what I entered would work, but no matter what I enter, I can't seem to get the result I want. If the user entered four for example, this should be the result:

```
O      O
 O    O
  O  O
   OO
```

Instead, this is what I get:

```
O    O
 O    O
  O    O
   O    O
```

This is my code:

```
    int N = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter a value between 2 and 10.");
    N = keyNum.nextInt();
    for (int a = 0; a < N; a++) 
    {
        System.out.println("");
        for (int b = 0; b < a; b++) 
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("O");

        //This loop is the one I`m having trouble with, everything else works fine!

        for (int c = (N - 1) * 2; c >= 0; c -= 2)
        {
            System.out.print(" ");  
        }
        System.out.print("O");
    }
```

I'm pretty new to programming so any kind of help would be appreciated! I genuinely want a good foundation so I don't develop bad coding habits, which is why I need help understanding what exactly is wrong with my loop.

Any kind of advice would be useful!

Comment: Your `c` loop is not using `a` for anything, and since you obviously need different number of spaces on different lines, how did you actually expect that loop to work correctly? Please re-think what you're trying to do.

Comment: You should stick to the Java Naming Conventions: variable names should start with lowercase. In your case, you should replace `N` by `n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Your current loop is a constant. You need to adjust it by `a` as well. That is, change this

```
for (int c = (N - 1) * 2; c >= 0; c -= 2)
{
    System.out.print(" ");  
}
```

to something like

```
for (int c = (N - a - 1) * 2; c > 0; c--) 
{
    System.out.print(" ");
}
```

and with no other changes I get (with N = 4)

```
O      O
 O    O
  O  O
   OO
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand what I was doing wrong now.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong to your second for loop. You did not change the number of spaces based on a. Try this:

```
    int N = 0;
    Scanner keyNum = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a value between 2 and 10.");
    N = keyNum.nextInt();
    for (int a = 0; a < N; a++) 
    {
        System.out.println("");
        for (int b = 0; b < a; b++) 
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("O");

        for (int c = (N - a - 1) * 2 ; c > 0; c -= 2)
        {
            System.out.print("  ");  
        }
        System.out.print("O");
    }
```

Comment: You need to explain what you changed and what was wrong with the OP's original comment